# How to link to other component in Angular

Tags: angular, router

I have standalone HomePage in one component in folder /app/main and another component Service in folder /app/service.
The HomePage has navbar menu and what I want to do is to redirect by anchor to Service Component where all the other components are migrated (login/register etc).
I tried to do with routerLink and router-outlet but when I done that, the Service component showed up under the main page but it should refresh and show up instead of the main.
With:
 `<a class="nav-link" href="C:\Users\wojtek\Desktop\Project\src\app\service\service.component.html">Service</a>`
It show error int the Console : "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/wojtek/Desktop/Project/src/app/service/service.component.html "

Here is my files tree:
[tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FRle.png)

app.module:

```
import { BrowserModule, Title} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SharedModule } from './service/shared.module';
import { MainPageComponent } from './main/main.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MainPageComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    ],
  providers: [
    Title
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MainPageComponent } from './main/main.component';
import { LoginPageComponent } from './service/components/login/login.component';
import { ResetPasswordComponent } from './service/components/reset-password/reset-password.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './service/components/register/register.component';
import { ServiceComponent } from './service/service.component';


const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '',  redirectTo: '/main', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'main', component: MainPageComponent},
    { path: 'login', component: LoginPageComponent },
    { path: 'reset-password', component: ResetPasswordComponent },
    { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
    { path: 'service', component: ServiceComponent}

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

shared.module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ColumnOneComponent } from './layouts/column-one/column-one.component';
import { ServiceComponent } from './service.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './layouts/navbar/navbar.component';
import { LoginPageComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register.component';
import { ResetPasswordComponent } from './components/reset-password/reset-password.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from '../app-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ServiceComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    ColumnOneComponent, 
    LoginPageComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    ResetPasswordComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  exports: [ColumnOneComponent, ServiceComponent]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Do someone has some solution for it?

Comment: Have you registered the Service component in routing?

Comment: @cse_vikashgupta yes, I have. Just updated the post with some code from it. Maybe it will be more clear.

Comment: `component showed up under the main page but it should refresh and show up instead of the main.` - this is default and proper behavior of Angular router. For "refresh and show up instead of the main" you need to use 2 different Angular applications and have a link from App1 to a page in App2. Btw, could you please show where did you put your router outlet?

Comment: Ah..that way :// I tried to put <router-outlet> in 2 places. 1 in app.component.html <app-main></app-main><router-outlet></router-outlet> and 2 in main.component.html at the end of the code. Each time it causes that service component appears at the end of the main page.